# Was there any official info as to why Always Somewhere sounds like Simple Man?

Tags: rock

As the title says, were there any reasons as to why Scorpions decided to use a similar rhythm to Lynyrd Skynyrd? When I first heard Simple Man, I thought at first it borrowed from Always Somewhere, then I found out it was released first.

Comment: @Brahadeesh Simple Man by Lynyrd Skynyrd and Always Somewhere by Scorpions. They can be searched across the Internet. Is putting links required for this case?

Answer (score 0):

I assume it was in homage to skynyrds 1977 plane crash that lost lead singer and leader Ronnie van zant as the song almost somewhere came out the year later. A lot  of bands were doing there own little tributes at the time. I know they were fans of each others work. Ronnie always loved European bands especially The Stones and Bad Company.